# Error in creating relationship one-to-one

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Good day!

I have two classes:

```swift
class OfficeModel: Object {

    var id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    @objc dynamic var city: String?
    @objc dynamic var address: String?
    @objc dynamic var phone: String?

    @objc dynamic var coordinate: OfficeСoordinates?

    convenience init(json: JSON) {
        self.init()
        self.id.value = json["Id"].int
        self.city = json["City"].string
        self.address = json["Address"].string
        self.coordinate = OfficeСoordinates(json: json["Coordinates"])
    }
}

class OfficeСoordinates: Object {

    var latitude = RealmOptional<Double>()
    var longitude = RealmOptional<Double>()

    convenience init(json: JSON) {
        self.init()

        self.latitude.value = json["Latitude"].double
        self.longitude.value = json["Longitude"].double
    }
}
```

The first time you access realm, the following error occurs:

[image]

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates', Error Code=1}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181
>   2017-12-21 13:19:05.559834+0500 EnergoIndividual[73534:5337172] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates', Error Code=1}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181

Declared the property @objc dynamic var coordinate: OfficeСoordinates? as indicated on this page: [enter link description here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-the-realm-framework)

[image]

Tell me, please, what is the error here?

Realm framework version: 3.0.2

Realm Object Server version: n/a

Xcode version: 9.1

iOS/OSX version: iOS11

Dependency manager + version: Cocoapods 1.3.1

Comment: Unrelated, but as the docs clearly state, properties of type `RealmOptional` should be declared using `let`, since directly assigning values to them won't work.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes, but I have a custom class as a property

Comment: I meant you should change `var id = RealmOptional<Int>()` to `let id = RealmOptional<Int>()` and the same for `latitude` and `longitude` in `OfficeСoordinates`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor interesting advice, but, unfortunately, the same error

Comment: As I've said in my first comment, it's not the cause of the issue, but it's still bad coding practice :)

Comment: @DávidPásztor, Thanks, I'll take a note :)